# Adding a Pilot light to a switch that indicates actual power draw

Tags: pilot-light

Thanks for your help.
I have 2 heated water lines each with a dedicated circuit and simple switches next to the panel to switch between summer (off) and winter (on).
These circuits go to receptacles in to which the heating traces are plugged.
The problem I have is that there is no way to know whether the heaters are actually working.  So I am thinking about a pilot light.
It seems to me that the switches with pilot lights that are available (insert favourite big box store here) will glow on if the switch is making power available to the circuit.  But ... they don't provide feedback as to whether the load is actually drawing current.
If my heater dies on me, I will only find out when there is a full-on plumbing disaster.

So can anyone advise as to whether there is an easy and efficient way to know whether current is actually being drawn when my switches are on?
I see indicator lights on various websites available at 120V, could I just wire one of these in series right at the switch?  Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that there may be other options. I assume you're heating the water lines to keep them from freezing. Where are they located? Might it be easier/more cost effective to insulate? More details may get you options you'd not considered.

Answer (score 1):

Receptacles? Use a plug-in power meter. Preferably not a sketchy unlisted one from Amazon Direct or Aliexpress, preferred suppliers of stuff that's not safe and will burn your house down, but that's fine because you are technically the idiot that imported it so they are off the hook for selling unsafe goods.

You want one that's actually tested by a Nationally Recognized Laboratory, such as UL or ETL, not one with a likely faked CE mark that means nothing.

Example of a listed unit, not a recommendation. I do own one, but I have no other relationship with them.

[image: Kill-A-Watt meter image from P3 international]

While you could also wire in an ammeter or power meter near the switch, that's generally far more complicated (and expensive) than plugging one of these in and setting the switch to show Watts or Amperes (either of which will tell you when the thing attached is drawing power.) I have a couple of those for a circuit where one of these won't work, and not only did they cost a lot more, one of them died for no particularly obvious reason. I'm saving the current transformer from it, but it was not good lifetime for the investment...

At a far more complicated and expensive level, one of those systems where all your circuits have current transformers installed and you can dissect use to your heart's content on your smartphone or computer would also work, if the heaters have their own circuit or circuits.

Answer (score 0):

You can not put an indicator in series or those 120v pilot lights they would go up in smoke.

there are things called current transformers that you can put around the wire and when there is a load a meter can show the value or a light can illuminate.

fancy CT’s have electronics that can set off an alarm if the current falls below a set point (a heat element failing with one still working these get a bit more expensive but cost is off topic.

Comment: Would a watt meter work?  OP says the heat tapes are plugged in,  would need to keep an eye on it to see if it is working or not.

Comment: Most watt meters are forms of CT’s or mostl inexpensive ones are solid state using hall affect sensor to measure the field strength.